# How to return promise from function: facebookConnectPlugin.api(String requestPath, Array permissions, Function success, Function failure)

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have the function

```
 facebookConnectPlugin.api(String requestPath, Array permissions, Function success, Function failure)
```

which I got from the phonegap API for facebook.
I have created success and failure functions. 
I need to wait for success/ failure to end and then continue.
How to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
apiWithPromise: function(requestPath, permissions) {
    var task = $q.defer();
    facebookConnectPlugin.api(requestPath, permissions, function(data) {
        // do something with your data here
        task.resolve(data);
    }, function(error) {
        // handle your error here
        task.reject(error);
    });
    return task.promise;
}
```

Obviously you will need to wrap this inside of a service or similar and have a reference to `facebookConnectPlugin`. You will need to declare a dependency on `$q`